# Why binding doesn't work in Polymer element?

Tags: polymer

I have some problems with binding. I am using Polymer 1.0.
For now I am creating an object with data in attached function. 
This example is really simple but doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
 <dom-module id="photo-block">
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <div class="photo-wrapper layout horizontal">
            <div class="flex relative big">
                <iron-image class="placeholder-color fit" src="{{photos.big}}" sizing="cover" preload fade></iron-image>
            </div>
            <div class="flex layout vertical">
                <div class="flex relative">
                    <iron-image class="placeholder-color fit" src="{{photos.small.0}}" sizing="cover" preload fade></iron-image>
                </div>
                <div class="flex relative hidden-xs">
                    <iron-image class="placeholder-color fit" src="{{photos.small.1}}" sizing="cover" preload fade></iron-image>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
   </dom-module>
    <script>
           Polymer({
            is: 'photo-block',
            properties: {
                photos: Object
            },
            attached: function() {
                this.photos = {
                    big: '/images/photos/YDXJ0696.jpg',
                    small: ['/images/photos/YDXJ0804.jpg', '/images/photos/YDXJ0811.jpg']
                };
                console.log(this.photos);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

In the console, I get that object, but even binding in  doesn't work.. What I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding actually works, the problem are the style/attributes you use on the `<iron-image>` element.

Try to change the first image element like this:

```
<iron-image src="{{photos.big}}" preload fade></iron-image>
```

the images will show up.

If you use the `sizing` attribute set to "cover", you need to specify an height and a width for you `<iron-image>` element.